# Change window position on screen

Tags: linux, haskell, window-managers, xmonad

I'm new to Haskell and Xmonad, so I downloaded [this](https://github.com/Axarva/dotfiles-2.0) beautiful configuration by Axarva. I'm starting to tweak it to my liking, and something that I definitively want to change is the launcher on the bottom.

So far, I managed to place it up on top with the `tint2conf` GUI, just like the image below:

[image]

But, as you can see, I have all that space below that I am using for nothing. So, I'd like to place all my windows lower, and make them a little bit bigger. How could I do this?

I tried to change the hooks layout in the `xmonad.hs` config file

```
      -- hooks, layouts
        manageHook = myManageHook, 
        layoutHook = gaps [(L,30), (R,30), (U,40), (D,60)] $ spacingRaw True (Border 10 10 10 10) True (Border 10 10 10 10) True $ smartBorders $ myLayout,
        handleEventHook    = myEventHook,
        logHook            = myLogHook,
        startupHook        = myStartupHook >> addEWMHFullscreen
    }
```

Played with the `(U,X)` and `(D,X)` values but it did not seem to work. When changing `(U,X)` from `(U,40)` to `(U,30)` or `(U,60)`, and reloading the session with `$mod+q`, the windows do not seem to change. The same happens if I log out and start a new session. When I try to do the same for the `(D,X)` values, I get the same result.

I also tried using the `tint2conf` GUI for this purpose, but I cannot find any setting to do what I want to do.

EDIT 2:

Setting `layoutHook = gaps [(L,30), (R,30), (U,50), (D,10)] $ spacingRaw True (Border 10 10 10 10) True (Border 10 10 10 10) True $ smartBorders $ myLayout,` gets the windows in the position I need. However, this layout only loads when pressing `$mod+Shift+Space`. New windows still open with the default layout.

Comment: Please be more specific about what "played with" means, and what actions and observations you take and make that lead you to say "it did not seem to work".

Comment: @DanielWagner It means I just edited the values, from example from (U,40) to (U,30) and U(60). Also from (D,60) to (D,80) and (D,30). It did nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that your modified config still compiles? Have you tried minimizing your config to find the smallest config that still has the problem (of ignoring the numbers you enter)?

Comment: (There is nothing obvious in the code you are showing here that would explain the behavior you claim to be seeing.)

Comment: @DanielWagner thank you for the answer, it made me look deeper into it. That XMonad.layoutHook only triggers when pressing $mod+Shift+Space. If I reload the configuration and do that, I can see the changes. Still, every time I open a new window it loads a default layout (that I do not know where it is in the config file) instead of the XMonad.layoutHook with the proper values that I need. The full config file is in the Axarva's github.

Comment: Ah, yes, I always forget how much of the layout stuff is squirreled away between restarts. You might try manually running `xmonad --replace` to completely reset all of `xmonad`'s state (though you will lose the positions/workspace assignments of existing windows, as that's part of the state that gets reset).